# MacBook Pro took a small tumble has minor scuffs on the right side

Tags: macbook-pro, scratches

My MacBook Pro took a small tumble off of my recliner last night and scuffed the right side from the brick of the fireplace. I just took my case off last week because the case was looking pretty bad and of course, as soon as I take it off it falls for the first time. My Macbook has been kept PERFECT and this little scuff really REALLY bothers me. I know its silly, but I'm a perfectionist and can't get over it! Any experience with repairs on this? I'm not expecting it to be fixed for free, but wondering about a price range etc...[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you can do without replacing the entire aluminum case, which probably isn't worth the trouble.

- Since it's cosmetic damage, Apple's warranty won't cover it.
- Maybe if you found a really skilled machinist, they could make it look better. But it would probably mess up the labels on the ports, so not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard, Trackpad, Battery and Topcase is one module, so is the display. So probably driple-digit, close to four-digit. Selling yours and buying a new one would probably even be cheaper.